# ApplicationContextInitializer not called when deploying Spring boot app to tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to deploy Spring boot war in tomcat 8.0.32. I've ApplicationContextInitializer class defined something like as shown below. However, when I start tomcat, initialize method of ApplicationContextInitializer never get's called. I'm doing something wrong here. Thanks for your help.

```
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        app.addInitializers(new ApplicationContextInitializer<?>[] { new DemoInitializer() });
        app.run(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to override createSpringApplicationBuilder in Application class and set initializer in SpringApplicationBuilder. That worked for me!

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Spring Boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-convert-an-existing-application-to-spring-boot), you need to add the `ApplicationContextInitializer` to the `SpringApplicationBuilder` by overriding the `configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder)` method when starting as a war. You can make the Initializer available to both the executable application and the war like this (where `CustomInitializer` is your `ApplicationContextInitializer`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return configureApplication(builder);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        configureApplication(new SpringApplicationBuilder()).run(args);
    }

    private static SpringApplicationBuilder configureApplication(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(Application.class).initializers(new CustomInitializer());
    }

}
```